Cannot get IP address with Dig
Every time I do dig www.example.com, I do not get an answer section. What do I do?

And yes, I did try using sudo:

I just still seem lost on what to do next.

Use an actual site for your dig tests, not a domain that doesnt exist (www.example.com actually doesnt exist)  Try dig google.com

Screenshots indicate you're running Kali, which is off-topic. I flagged as off-topic.

@ThomasWard www.example.com actually does exist, it resolves to 93.184.215.14 and even has a website that states that it's an example domain.

The output you posted shows flags: qr aa rd ra. The presence of aa flag (authority) signals that the nameserver you are querying (192.168.64.1) treats itself as authoritative for example.com domain (which can be visible from AUTHORITY section in the answer) and returns an authoritative NXDOMAIN reply telling you that the domain does not exist (hence lack of ANSWER section).
So the actual problem is that your nameserver is effectively "hijacking" the example.com domain and responds to queries for this domain by itself, instead of forwarding them to proper nameservers for this domain, which in this case are IANA nameservers a.iana-servers.net and b.iana-servers.net.
This nameserver is - either accidentally, or on purpose - wrongly configured, and that's the source of your problem.
Try to query another nameserver with dig, for example Google's 8.8.8.8: dig @8.8.8.8 www.example.com.

@ThomasWard After doing some additional investigation, I edited my answer and corrected the mistakes.
